# IoError 2032 when trying to log in

Tags: facebook, mobile, actionscript, ioerror

I'm getting IoError 2032 when attempting to login from the mobile actionscript-facebook api.  Specifically I'm getting this error on my android 4.0 device.  Strange thing is, it was working fine about a week ago. Anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be related to the `URLLoader` and there is an [issue opened](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/issues/detail?id=409) for this in facebook-actionscript-api.